# Confused about finding Pre-image by a theorem

Tags: general-topology

Let S = $ \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^{2}| x^{2} + y^{2} \leq 1 \} $
Show that this set is closed.

I find a continuous function $f$ given by $f(x,y) = x^{2} + y^{2} - 1$ But how do I find the pre-image of f so that I can state that the pre - image set is closed and therefore the set S is closed? And can somehow explain how they got it too?

Comment: It may not be best choice of continuous function $f$, but you can work with it.  Figure out what the image $f(S)$ is, that it is closed in $\mathbb{R}$, and then verify that $S$ is the pre-image of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To talk about pre-image, you must first specify a subset of $\Bbb R$.  In this case, 
$$S=f^{-1}([-1,0]).$$

Since $f$ is continuous and $[0,1]$ is closed, what can you say about $S$ now?

To see that $S=f^{-1}([-1,0])$:

$$\begin{align}
(x,y)\in S & \iff 0\le x^2+y^2\le 1\\
& \iff -1\le x^2+y^2-1\le 0\\
& \iff f(x,y)\in [-1,0]\\
& \iff (x,y)\in f^{-1}([-1,0]).
\end{align}$$

Comment: Ok then S is Closed. But What I don't get is why is it just [0,1] ? and not like [-1,1]. I really don't get that. Please explain a bit further.

Comment: I'll expand my answer.

Comment: Sorry, it should be $[-1,0]$.

Comment: Thanks. That was the best explanation I've seen.